# How to load a matrix as a pointer to pointer to struct Vector

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, vector, struct

I have a struct that I called Vector which contains an array and its size. I populated it in the code as follows:

```
        vec1
  row1   1
  row1   2
  row1   4
  row1   5
```

What I want to do is to have an array of Vectors (a matrix, which is probably a pointer to pointer to struct?) so that I could have loaded data as follows

```
        vec1  vec2  vec3
  row1   1     3     8  
  row1   2     5     9
  row1   4     6     10
  row1   5     7     11
```

here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int ncol = 4;
int nrow = 3;

typedef struct {
  int size_array;
  int *array;
} Vector ;

int main()
{
  Vector *vec1 = (Vector *) malloc(sizeof(Vector));
  vec1->array = (int *) malloc(ncol * sizeof(int));
  vec1->size_array = ncol;
  vec1->array[0] = 1;
  vec1->array[1] = 2;
  vec1->array[2] = 4;
  vec1->array[3] = 5;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment @chux-ReinstateMonica. I would use this matrix as an array of indices (which wouldn't be negative). This is why I originaly chose `size_t` as type. But indeed for the sake of the scope of the question, I changed the type to `int` after your comment. Do you have an idea about how I should proceed forward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simplify allocations**

Use the `ptr = malloc(sizeof ptr[0] * n)` model

```
// Vector *vec1 = (Vector *) malloc(sizeof(Vector));
Vector *vec1 = malloc(sizeof vec1[0] * n);
```

**Check allocation results**

**Allocate for `nrows`**

```
Vector *matrix1 = malloc(sizeof vec1 * nrow);
if (matrix1 == NULL) TBD_code();
for (size_t r = 0; r < nrow; r++) {
  matrix1[r].array = malloc(sizeof matrix1[r].array[0] * ncol);
  if (matrix1[r].array == NULL) TBD_code();
  for (size_t c = 0; c < ncol; c++) {
    matrix1[r].array[c] = TBD_code;
  }
}
```

**Alternatives**

To form a *matrix* directly, we could use

```
typedef struct {
  int rows, columns;
  int **m;
} Matrix;
```

or

```
typedef struct {
  int rows, columns;
  int *m[]; // variable logic array
} Matrix;
```

or others.

Comment: many thanks for your answer @chux-ReinstateMonica.  I ll have to study it carerully

Comment: I would use `size_t`

Comment: @0___________ Yes, `size_t` for sizing and indexing and `int` for a sample type.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the dimension for your `nrow` to the malloc call for your vector. Then you can allocate your vector data in a loop.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int ncol = 4;
int nrow = 3;

typedef struct {
  int size_array;
  int *array;
} Vector ;

int main()
{
  int i;
  Vector *vectors;

  vectors = (Vector *) malloc(nrow * sizeof(Vector));
  
  for (i = 0; i < nrow; i++)
  {
    Vector* vec1 = &vectors[i];
    vec1->array = (int *) malloc(ncol * sizeof(int));
    vec1->size_array = ncol;
    vec1->array[0] = 1;
    vec1->array[1] = 2;
    vec1->array[2] = 4;
    vec1->array[3] = 5;  
  }

  for (i = 0; i < nrow; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < vectors[i].size_array; j++)
    {
      printf("%d ", vectors[i].array[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Should print

```
1 2 4 5
1 2 4 5
1 2 4 5
```

Comment: many thanks for your answer @EMoffat. I ll have to study it carerully

Answer (score 0):

I would use flexible array members instead as it simplifies allocation and freeing. To have a vector of `Vector` I would also use additional struct to be consistent (ie remember the number of `Vector`s in that new vector)

Also, use **functions** - do not program in the `main` function. It logically organizes the code and makes coding *much* easier and less error-prone. It allows you to easily **test** logical parts of your code.

```
typedef struct 
{
    size_t size_array;
    int array[];
} Vector;

typedef  struct
{
    size_t size;
    Vector *array[];
}VectorOfVector;

Vector *newVector(size_t size)
{
    Vector *vect = malloc(size *sizeof(vect -> array[0]) + sizeof(*vect));
    if(vect) vect -> size_array = size;
    return vect;
}

VectorOfVector *newVectorOfVector(size_t size, size_t vectsize)
{
    VectorOfVector *vect = malloc(size *sizeof(vect -> array[0]) + sizeof(*vect));
    if(vect)
    { 
        vect -> size = size;
        for(size_t index = 0; index < size; index++)
        {
            vect -> array[index] = newVector(vectsize);
            if(!vect -> array[index]) { /* handle allocation error */ }
        }
    }
    return vect;
}

void freeVectorOfVectors(VectorOfVector *vect)
{
    if(vect)
    {
        for(size_t index = 0; index < size; index++)
        {
            free(vect -> array[index]);
        }
    }
    free(vect);
}
```

Also use the correct type for sizes (`size_t`)

Example usage (will allocate random size vectors):

```
void initVectorOfVector(const VectorOfVector *vect)
{
    if(vect)
    {
        for(size_t index = 0; index < vect -> size; index++)
        {
            if(vect -> array[index])
            {
                for(size_t indexv = 0; indexv < vect -> array[index] -> size_array; indexv++)
                {
                    vect -> array[index] -> array[indexv] = rand() % 100;
                }            
            }
        }
    }
}

void printVectorOfVector(const VectorOfVector *vect)
{
    if(vect)
    {
        for(size_t index = 0; index < vect -> size; index++)
        {
            if(vect -> array[index])
            {
                for(size_t indexv = 0; indexv < vect -> array[index] -> size_array; indexv++)
                {
                    printf("%5d", vect -> array[index] -> array[indexv]);
                }
            }
            else printf("This Vector was not allocated");
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    VectorOfVector *vect = newVectorOfVector(rand() & 20 + 1,rand() & 20 + 1);
    initVectorOfVector(vect);
    printVectorOfVector(vect);
    freeVectorOfVectors(vect);    
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Kvdr1on8z